# Отслеживание источника и цены регистрации analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Подскажите, кто может подсказать или дать материалы с детальным описанием как произвести настройку analytics для сервиса.

Цель задачи
 1. Настроить воронку 
1.1 понять сколько стоит регистрация и какая рекламная кампания дает лучший результат по регистрации 
Как настроить отслеживания достижения цели регистрации трафика который приходит из Adwords ?
 2. Понимать какие рекламные источники привлекли реальную продажу ?

Comment: А стандартные отчёты с настроенной на регистрацию целью не решают вашу задачу?

Comment: Да вот пока, нет, не решают, а если и решают то немогу понять как...


Есть исчерпывающие материалы по настройке отслеживанию эффективности рекламных кампаний ?

Comment: Сколько стоит регистрация - тут нужно импортировать все расходы в ГА и смотреть отчёт по компаниям. Далее настраиваете цель на регистрацию и в вычисляемой метрике считаете расход на кампанию/количество регистраций.